# Inserting 8K+ data to table sometimes works, sometimes not

Tags: sql-server, insert, varchar

I have to insert data from an 1450 column excel file to an SQL table. The only possible way I think if I have table parts, for example 3 of 500 column tables.
My problem is that some cells on the sheet contains 5-10 chars, and some can contain up to 100 chars.
I created a table that contains 500 columns, the columns are VARCHAR(MAX).
If I use the following insert statement, I don't get any error messages:

```
INSERT INTO [table] ([column1], [column2]) 
VALUES 
(
CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE('A', 5000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
)
```

This is 120.000 characters total in one row. I get no error message when I run it, it inserts the data to the table, I also can read it, everything works fine.

BUT, if I try to run the following query, I got the error message:

```
Cannot create a row of size 13071 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.
```

The query:

```
INSERT INTO [table]
VALUES (
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST(REPLICATE('A', 50) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
)
```

The second query contains 500 * 50 (total 25.000) 'A' characters, this is a lot less than the 120.000 chars, but I get the overflow error I wrote above.

Please help me guys, I have no idea, what is wrong... How can I insert everything I need without error? I tried everything that can be found on the internet in this topic, but nothing helped, TEXT type is not working, REBUILD table also didn't have any effect, etc...

Comment: The beginning of your challenge is an excel document with 1400+ columns. How is that even manageable? I am guessing that is an automated export from something? Can you break that into manageable chunks before it gets to you? And tables with 500 columns is really not much better. I suspect you are trying to morph into something usable?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to manage this template somehow, I don't have any other options.

Comment: Then you will have to break it into more tables. The max row size is 8060, you are trying to insert 25,000.

Comment: But why is it working when I use the first query? That inserts 120K characters, this is far more than 8060 bytes, and the insert runs without any problem.

Comment: And the query inserts 2x120K chars, because I insert them in 2 columns. I also checked using LEN and DATALENGTH, they both confirm that 2x120K characters and bytes have been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The varchar(max) is LOB data, it's stored in-row if it fits in row, otherwise it puts in row a 24-bytes pointer to LOB root structure that contains pointers to LOB pages.
So in your case of 500 LOB pages there will be 500 pointers x 24 bytes = 12000 bytes + 2 bytes for row offset array: 2 x 500 = 1000, and we have 13000 bytes;may be I don't remember what other overhead should be stored besides these 13000 bytes but you cannot fit them into 1 page anyway.
In case you put only 2 columns the row will store only 2 x 24 + 2 x 2 bytes of data, the 2 pointers only, so there is no problem at all. The eventual data (120.000 caracters are not stored in-row, but in chunks of LOB pages that form a LOB tree